How do I restore user defined charts?
I have implemented a save/restore feature in my web app, which uses grid.api.getState() to capture/save the grid state, and then an onLoad function which sets the grid's initialState to the saved states to restore it. It looks roughly like this:
<template>
    <div>
        <ag-grid-vue v-if="gridVisible" ref="gridRef" rowModelType="clientSide" :gridOptions="gridOptions"
            :sideBar="['columns', 'filters']" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="onLoad">Load</button>
    <button onclick="onSave">Save</button>
</template>

<script setup>
    import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css";
    import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css";
    import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
    import { ref, reactive } from "vue"

    const gridOptions = reactive({})
    const gridVisible = ref(true)

    var savedState = undefined

    // ... some code to populate gridOptions with initial data

    function onSave() {
        savedState = gridRef.value.api.getState()
    }

    function onLoad() {
        gridVisible.value = false;

        // put the initialisation into the back of the ioservice so that the grid is
        // disabled before we start
        setTimeout(() => {
            gridRef.value.api.gridOptions.initialState = state.gridState;
            gridVisible.value = true;
        });
    }
</script>

This works for filters, grouping, column selections, etc. But if a user saves a state with a user-defined chart in it, then saving/restoring this way causes the selected cells to be visible, but the chart itself disappears. How can I capture/restore the chart as well?

As per David Glickman's response, I've tried modifying my onSave and onLoad functions to include the getChartModels() and restoreChart() methods:
function onSave() {
  savedState = {
    grid: gridRef.value.api.getState(),
    chart: gridRef.value.api.getChartModel()
}

function onLoad() {
  gridVisible.value = false;

  // put the initialisation into the back of the ioservice so that the grid is
  // disabled before we start
  setTimeout(() => {
    gridRef.value.api.gridOptions.initialState = state.grid;
    gridVisible.value = true;
    if (state.chartState.length != 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        gridRef.value.api.restoreChart(state.chart);
      });
    }
  });
}

However, when I do this I see no chart and a warning in the console:

ServerSideView.vue:73 AG Grid - unable to create chart as no range is
selected.

Interestingly, the selection does restore, and I can see the cells that were selected when I did the save.

Can you add some more code, so that it will be helpful to understand your case better?

@YashMaheshwari I've modified the question to hopefully make it clearer.

A chart model that represents all the state information about the rendered charts can be obtained using getChartModels(). This returns a list of models with information about the charts that are currently rendered from the grid.
These models can then be supplied to the restoreChart grid api method to restore the chart.
See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/integrated-charts-api-save-restore-charts/ for more details.

Thanks, I tried implementing this (see edit to my post) but no success, I'm getting a unable to create chart as no range is selected warning now.

I also tried adding restoreChart to the onGridReady callback but that had the same effect.
